# How do I create a "Project overview" in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005

I´m using Visual Studio 2008 / C# and SQL Server 2005 to create a tool where people can allocate resources for periods of times, and in certain places, and with certain tasks.

They like the implementation, but they want to have a better Overview - that is, Dates as Columns, and allocations as horizontal coloured sausages (rows).

Like an ordinary project overview, you know?

Now, do you have any tips on how I should do it (create a Project Overview)? Just high level tips, that´s what I need - I can dig by myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I think, that the overview you are talking about is actually called Gantt chart.

How to implement it? Well, I can bet that you can find a lot of implementations of gantt chart controls, for WinForms, WPF or ASP.NET - whichever you need. I bet it would be the fastest and most cost-efficient way to do it.

If, for some reason, you need to implementit yourself - then you'll just have to create your own contorl, but I strongly recommend using one of the existing ones - it'll save you a lot of time and nerve

Comment: Thanks Hassan! Searched and found this: http://dlhsoft.com/GanttChartLibrary/Home.aspx
  I think that it could do the trick - but I would prefer something cheaper. So I will go out hunting now...